# Performance considerations Postgresql Materialized View on JSONB. Is there an alternative

Tags: postgresql

I'm about to design a system that will store JSON data for users from their LinkedIn and GitHub accounts.

I will have a simple table with these columns

```
|--------|----------|-----------------------------------|
| UserId | Type     | Profile                           |
|--------|----------|-----------------------------------|
| 1      | LinkedIn | {name: 'david', skills: [{},{},{}]|
| 1      | GitHubIn | {name: 'david', repos:  [{},{},{}]|
| 2      | LinkedIn | {name: 'bill' , skills: [{},{},{}]|
| 2      | StackFlo | {name: 'bill' , badges: [{},{},{}]|
| 3      | GitHubIn | {name: 'bob'  , repos:  [{},{},{}]|
|--------|----------|-----------------------------------|
```

I have 100000+ users and anyone could update or connect new accounts at any time.

I want to create simple queryable views from this data in a flat denormalized structure.

One option is to use a materialized view that gets refreshed once a day.

This would give a flat data set that can be queried a quickly but the problem is that I would re-query the entire profile table every time and there may only be 10 or 20 or 100 actual changes in the table.

I know that incremental refreshes cannot be done with materialized views.

Another option might be to create a table for and use **upsert** by doing `INSERT ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT UPDATE`

Two Questions

1. Do I really need to worry about this processing time that it takes to recreate materialized views, or is it a baseless fear?
2. Is there is an alternative technique that is just as easy/flexible as materialized views, but deals with incremental data changes?

Current View looks something like this:

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS profile_stackoverflow_v1;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW profile_stackoverflow_v1 AS
  SELECT
    id as profile_id,
    profile->>'display_name' as display_name,
    profile->>'profile_image' as profile_image,
    profile->'badge_counts'->>'bronze' as bronze_badge_count,
    profile->'badge_counts'->>'silver' as silver_badge_count,
    profile->'badge_counts'->>'gold' as gold_badge_count
  FROM account_profiles
  WHERE type = 'StackFlo';

DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS profile_stackoverflow_badges_v1;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW profile_stackoverflow_badges_v1 AS
  SELECT
    ap.id as profile_id,
    badge->'badge_id' as stacko_badge_id,
    badge->'name' as badge_name,
    badge->'badge_type' as badge_type,
    badge->'award_count' as award_count
  FROM account_profiles ap,
    jsonb_array_elements(ap.profile->'badges') as badge
  WHERE type = 'StackFlo';
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Whether your fears are 'baseless' and whether the materialization takes 'too long' are inversely-correlated to the processing power of your Pg install as well as the API calls-per-second of the host systems you are extracting profiles from.  In General: Yes, be concerned about processing time (and cost of compute resources) when creating materialized views.

2) A failed-constraint UPSERT-based solution will have to run on a periodic basis just as the materialized view refreshes will; the greater the time between runs, presumably the larger number of failed constraints and updates will [inevitably] occur.  The resource cost of lots of failed constraints might slow the UPSERT down relative to wholesale replacement.--but only after a significant fraction of the entire set is marked 'dirty' by some host-system update.

3) **The ideal option** is to investigate the APIs supplied by the various source systems to find if a "dirty row" flag is available to show you which records are recently inserted or updated. -- You do not want to query their entire subscribership [or even the fraction you are interested in] to find out for yourself!

In the absence of that availability (which I did not personally look for) **my suggestion is to try the UPSERT option with a very short interval** (of say 15 minutes if your API credits will allow) so that the number of updated rows (and inserts too) are small. This should result in most your system remaining in sync with the source systems without too many row-changes to process every interval.

Comment: Forgot to mention: that you should verify that your use-case for this system is aligned with the terms-of-use for the source system(s) you are extracting profiles from!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reponse Jason